# node js execute multiple query and try to render it

Tags: node.js

I've some problem when try to get multiple query and render it to hbs. my code is

```
  app.get('/',(req, res, next) => {
  let sql = "SELECT * FROM employee; SELECT * FROM data_survey"

  let query = conn.query(sql, (err, results, survey)=>{
    if(err) throw err;
    res.render('index',{
      data1: results[0],
      data: survey
    });
    console.log(survey);
  });
});
```

The 1st query show the data from database but when i try to get the result of 2nd in log doesn't show the data from database and and just show the config of the db

```
 [
  [
    FieldPacket {
      catalog: 'def',      
      db: 'db_ta',
      table: 'employee',   
      orgTable: 'employee',
      name: 'user_id',
      orgName: 'user_id',
      charsetNr: 63,
      length: 11,
      type: 3,
      flags: 16905,
      decimals: 0,
      default: undefined,
      zeroFill: false,
      protocol41: true
    },
    FieldPacket {
      catalog: 'def',
      db: 'db_ta',
      table: 'employee',
      orgTable: 'employee',
      name: 'employee_id',
      orgName: 'employee_id',
      charsetNr: 33,
      length: 30,
      type: 253,
      flags: 20483,
      decimals: 0,
      default: undefined,
      zeroFill: false,
      protocol41: true
    },
    FieldPacket {
      catalog: 'def',
      db: 'db_ta',
      table: 'employee',
      orgTable: 'employee',
      name: 'username',
      orgName: 'username',
      charsetNr: 33,
      length: 60,
      type: 253,
      flags: 4097,
      decimals: 0,
      default: undefined,
      zeroFill: false,
      protocol41: true
    },
    FieldPacket {
      catalog: 'def',
      db: 'db_ta',
      table: 'employee',
      orgTable: 'employee',
      name: 'password',
      orgName: 'password',
      charsetNr: 33,
      length: 60,
      type: 253,
      flags: 4097,
      decimals: 0,
      default: undefined,
      zeroFill: false,
      protocol41: true
    },
    FieldPacket {
      catalog: 'def',
      db: 'db_ta',
      table: 'employee',
      orgTable: 'employee',
      name: 'serial_number',
      orgName: 'serial_number',
      charsetNr: 33,
      length: 150,
      type: 253,
      flags: 4097,
      decimals: 0,
      default: undefined,
      zeroFill: false,
      protocol41: true
    }
  ],
  [
    FieldPacket {
      catalog: 'def',
      db: 'db_ta',
      table: 'data_survey',
      orgTable: 'data_survey',
      name: 'nik',
      orgName: 'nik',
      charsetNr: 33,
      length: 60,
      type: 253,
      flags: 20487,
      decimals: 0,
      default: undefined,
      zeroFill: false,
      protocol41: true
    },
    FieldPacket {
      catalog: 'def',
      db: 'db_ta',
      table: 'data_survey',
      orgTable: 'data_survey',
      name: 'nama',
      orgName: 'nama',
      charsetNr: 33,
      length: 300,
      type: 253,
      flags: 4097,
      decimals: 0,
      default: undefined,
      zeroFill: false,
      protocol41: true
    },
    FieldPacket {
      catalog: 'def',
      db: 'db_ta',
      table: 'data_survey',
      orgTable: 'data_survey',
      name: 'ttl',
      orgName: 'ttl',
      charsetNr: 33,
      length: 300,
      type: 253,
      flags: 4097,
      decimals: 0,
      default: undefined,
      zeroFill: false,
      protocol41: true
    },
    FieldPacket {
      catalog: 'def',
      db: 'db_ta',
      table: 'data_survey',
      orgTable: 'data_survey',
      name: 'jenis',
      orgName: 'jenis',
      charsetNr: 33,
      length: 60,
      type: 253,
      flags: 4097,
      decimals: 0,
      default: undefined,
      zeroFill: false,
      protocol41: true
    },
    FieldPacket {
      catalog: 'def',
      db: 'db_ta',
      table: 'data_survey',
      orgTable: 'data_survey',
      name: 'gol',
      orgName: 'gol',
      charsetNr: 33,
      length: 300,
      type: 253,
      flags: 4097,
      decimals: 0,
      default: undefined,
      zeroFill: false,
      protocol41: true
    },
    FieldPacket {
      catalog: 'def',
      db: 'db_ta',
      table: 'data_survey',
      orgTable: 'data_survey',
      name: 'alamat',
      orgName: 'alamat',
      charsetNr: 33,
      length: 300,
      type: 253,
      flags: 4097,
      decimals: 0,
      default: undefined,
      zeroFill: false,
      protocol41: true
    },
    FieldPacket {
      catalog: 'def',
      db: 'db_ta',
      table: 'data_survey',
      orgTable: 'data_survey',
      name: 'rtrw',
      orgName: 'rtrw',
      charsetNr: 33,
      length: 300,
      type: 253,
      flags: 4097,
      decimals: 0,
      default: undefined,
      zeroFill: false,
      protocol41: true
    },
    FieldPacket {
      catalog: 'def',
      db: 'db_ta',
      table: 'data_survey',
      orgTable: 'data_survey',
      name: 'kelurahan',
      orgName: 'kelurahan',
      charsetNr: 33,
      length: 300,
      type: 253,
      flags: 4097,
      decimals: 0,
      default: undefined,
      zeroFill: false,
      protocol41: true
    },
    FieldPacket {
      catalog: 'def',
      db: 'db_ta',
      table: 'data_survey',
      orgTable: 'data_survey',
      name: 'kecamatan',
      orgName: 'kecamatan',
      charsetNr: 33,
      length: 150,
      type: 253,
      flags: 4097,
      decimals: 0,
      default: undefined,
      zeroFill: false,
      protocol41: true
    },
    FieldPacket {
      catalog: 'def',
      db: 'db_ta',
      table: 'data_survey',
      orgTable: 'data_survey',
      name: 'agama',
      orgName: 'agama',
      charsetNr: 33,
      length: 300,
      type: 253,
      flags: 4097,
      decimals: 0,
      default: undefined,
      zeroFill: false,
      protocol41: true
    },
    FieldPacket {
      catalog: 'def',
      db: 'db_ta',
      table: 'data_survey',
      orgTable: 'data_survey',
      name: 'status',
      orgName: 'status',
      charsetNr: 33,
      length: 150,
      type: 253,
      flags: 4097,
      decimals: 0,
      default: undefined,
      zeroFill: false,
      protocol41: true
    },
    FieldPacket {
      catalog: 'def',
      db: 'db_ta',
      table: 'data_survey',
      orgTable: 'data_survey',
      name: 'pekerjaan',
      orgName: 'pekerjaan',
      charsetNr: 33,
      length: 150,
      type: 253,
      flags: 4097,
      decimals: 0,
      default: undefined,
      zeroFill: false,
      protocol41: true
    },
    FieldPacket {
      catalog: 'def',
      db: 'db_ta',
      table: 'data_survey',
      orgTable: 'data_survey',
      name: 'kewarganegaraan',
      orgName: 'kewarganegaraan',
      charsetNr: 33,
      length: 30,
      type: 253,
      flags: 4097,
      decimals: 0,
      default: undefined,
      zeroFill: false,
      protocol41: true
    },
    FieldPacket {
      catalog: 'def',
      db: 'db_ta',
      table: 'data_survey',
      orgTable: 'data_survey',
      name: 'berlaku',
      orgName: 'berlaku',
      charsetNr: 33,
      length: 150,
      type: 253,
      flags: 4097,
      decimals: 0,
      default: undefined,
      zeroFill: false,
      protocol41: true
    },
    FieldPacket {
      catalog: 'def',
      db: 'db_ta',
      table: 'data_survey',
      orgTable: 'data_survey',
      name: 'time',
      orgName: 'time',
      charsetNr: 63,
      length: 19,
      type: 12,
      flags: 129,
      decimals: 0,
      default: undefined,
      zeroFill: false,
      protocol41: true
    },
    FieldPacket {
      catalog: 'def',
      db: 'db_ta',
      table: 'data_survey',
      orgTable: 'data_survey',
      name: 'location',
      orgName: 'location',
      charsetNr: 33,
      length: 196605,
      type: 252,
      flags: 4113,
      decimals: 0,
      default: undefined,
      zeroFill: false,
      protocol41: true
    },
    FieldPacket {
      catalog: 'def',
      db: 'db_ta',
      table: 'data_survey',
      orgTable: 'data_survey',
      name: 'survey_id',
      orgName: 'survey_id',
      charsetNr: 63,
      length: 11,
      type: 3,
      flags: 16901,
      decimals: 0,
      default: undefined,
      zeroFill: false,
      protocol41: true
    }
  ]
]
```

i've also already add `multipleStatements: true` in my connection. can you give me some solution?

Answer (score 0):

`results` will contain the results for all statements (if `multipleStatements` was enabled), see the documentation for more [information](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#multiple-statement-queries). So changing

```
res.render('index',{
  data1: results[0],
  data: survey
});
console.log(survey);
```

to

```
res.render('index',{
  data1: results, // return all results here instead of the first only
  data: survey
});
console.log(results);
```

should fix the issue.